# Call Action Filter / Attribute on a single parameter in method

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

How would one go about calling an action filter (or an attribute) on a single parameter in an action in a controller?

I have an action that accepts a string parameter that needs to be transformed before the action can continue using it (since it could arrive from the front-end both transformed OR original). I want to implement an attribute that intercepts the action, transforms the parameter, and then continues the action (similar to how the `[Bind]` attribute is called on specific parameters in an action).

The example action filter gets called if I call it on the whole action but I want it to be called only on specific parameters.

Example action:

```cs
public ActionResult CalculateFieldValue(string documentId, [FieldEscape]string fieldId)
{
    // Operations requiring the fieldId to be cleaned first...
}
```

Example action filter:

```cs
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter)]
public class FieldEscapeAttribute: ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // Replace the last occurence of "___" with ":" in the parameter value and then continue
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Comment: So you want ONE method to be compatible with TWO different inputs. Don't do that. Just don't. Use two methods for two different inputs. Overload the same method or encapsulate the shared logic into another method and share it. Yeah, this solution is not as fancy as you were looking for but it's a much more MAINTENIBLE ONE.

Comment: @PabloRecalde Unfortunately, the use case is being able to support newer API calls where the values are escaped in the front-end so such attributes are not needed. However, it also has to support legacy code that might not have the value escaped (or at least support it until it is refactored to clean the input as well). I recognize that it's a bad practice but I can't refactor the old API calls yet.

Comment: Also, the inputs are actually the same. They always represent a Field's ID value. However, sometimes in a specific case a part of that ID has to be escaped and is not always unescaped back to its original value (problematic legacy code). The attribute is meant to act as a validation layer that silently unescapes the ID back to its correct value before even passing it to the action, so that there's no need to write logic that specifically transforms the ID value in every action that requires it.

Comment: “The attribute is meant to act as a validation layer that silently un escapes the ID back to its correct value before passing it to the action” this is the kind of thinking you need to correct. Doing something like this is simply wrong, and hiding it away on an attribute is worst. You people will forget this is there and this will be the cause of a future bug. I hope you’re still around when this happens.